# setting visibility of a grid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, grid

i am using mvvm. i have a home page and in that i have 2 grid,one internal and another external..in the parent grid i have a data-grid.when am clicking on the row of the datagrid i need to make visible the child grid which contains the controls that is binded to the clicked row values.help me i didnt get any idea.pls help me..pls pls..

this is my xaml..

```
<Window x:Class="EmployeeRegistration.Home"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        xmlns:View="clr-namespace:EmployeeRegistration" WindowState="Maximized"

        Title="Home" Height="853" Width="1200"
        >
    <Window.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="#FF84BFC4" Offset="1" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Window.Background>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <View:EmployeeViewModel></View:EmployeeViewModel>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding GetEmployeeCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Control" x:Key="myErrorTemplate">
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2.75" Grid.Column="0">
                            <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="MyControl" Grid.Column="0"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource myErrorTemplate}" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Height="677" Width="1139"  Background="#FFC4DDD1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="2"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="48*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="65" />
            <RowDefinition Height="457*" />
            <!--<RowDefinition Height="35" />
            <RowDefinition Height="44"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="45" />
            <RowDefinition Height="49" />
            <RowDefinition Height="56" />
            <RowDefinition Height="43" />
            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
            <RowDefinition Height="37"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="39" />
            <RowDefinition Height="83*" />-->
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="538" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="538"/>

        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Name="lblEmployeeDetails" Content="EMPLOYEE DETAILS" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="26" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="117,10,125,0" Width="296" Grid.Row="1"></Label>



        <TextBlock Margin="0,-2,-6,9" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="141" Grid.Column="4" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <Button Name="btnNewEmployee"  Content="New Employee Registration" FontFamily="Calibri" Background="#FF2693A7" Foreground="White" />
        </TextBlock>
        <Label Name="lblEnterName" Grid.Row="2" Content="Enter Employee Name:" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="16" Margin="0,16,12,23"></Label>
        <TextBox Name="txtSearch" Text="{Binding Path=FirstName,Mode=OneWayToSource,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Grid.Row="2" Margin="166,18,0,21" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="186"></TextBox>
        <Button Name="btnSearch" Command="{Binding SearchEmployeeCommand}" Grid.Row="2" Content="Search" Margin="0,18,58,21" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="103"  Foreground="White" Background="Black"></Button>

        <DataGrid Grid.Row="3" x:Name="grdEmployee" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployee, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeDatatable, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  IsReadOnly="True" FontFamily="Calibri" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,26,39,0" Width="494" CanUserAddRows="False"  Background="#FF20E0BB" AlternatingRowBackground="#FF7CB4AB" Height="420" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Emp_id}" Header="Employee ID"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FirstName}" Header="FirstName"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding LastName}" Header="LastName"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Age}" Header="Age"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ZipCode}" Header="ZipCode"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PhoneNumber}" Header="PhoneNumber"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MobileNumber}" Header="MobileNumber"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Content="Edit" Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectEmployeeCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedEmployee}"  ></Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="532,10,-35,12" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="142" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="139" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="138" />

                <ColumnDefinition Width="154" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="67" />
            <RowDefinition Height="37"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="36" />
                <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                <RowDefinition Height="40" />
            <RowDefinition Height="44" />
            <RowDefinition Height="52" />
            <RowDefinition Height="54" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="50*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="47*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="42*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="106*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Label Name="lblHeading" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="UPDATE EMPLOYEE DETAILS" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="22"  VerticalAlignment="Center"  Height="71" Width="263" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="2,21,12,12" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1">
            </Label>
            <Label Content="*" Grid.Row="2" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,15,12" Name="lblReqField" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="49" Foreground="Red" />
            <Label Name="lblPersonalInfo" Content="PERSONAL INFO" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="20" Foreground="#FF1C48D8" Grid.Row="1" Height="37" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="270" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Height="37" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="lblFirstName" Content="FirstName"  FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="80" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="txtFirstName" Text="{Binding Path=FirstName,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"  BorderBrush="#FF179EB7"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130" Margin="0,3,0,0" />

            <Label Content="*" Grid.Row="3" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,15,12" Name="lblReqField1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="49" Foreground="Red" />
            <Label  Height="35" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="lblLastName" Content="LastName"  FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="142" Grid.Row="3" />
            <TextBox BorderBrush="#FF179EB7" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="txtLastName" Text="{Binding Path=LastName,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Margin="1,4,0,0" />

            <Label Content="*" Grid.Row="4" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,86,12" Name="lblReqField2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="19" Foreground="Red" />
            <Label  Height="35" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="lblDob" Content="DOB"  FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="16"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="56" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
            <DatePicker Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Name="dtpDob" Text="{Binding Path=Dob,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="129"  />


            <Label  Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="lblAge" Content="Age"  FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="16"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="142" Grid.Row="5" Margin="0,8,0,0" />
            <TextBox Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="txtAge" BorderBrush="#FF179EB7" IsReadOnly="True"  Text="{Binding Path=Age,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="138" Grid.Row="5" Margin="1,11,0,0" Grid.Column="1" />


            <Label  Height="45" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="lblAddressInfo" Content="ADDRESS INFO" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="20"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="142" Grid.Row="6" Margin="0,7,0,0" />


            <Label Content="*" Grid.Row="7" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,39,27" Name="lblReqField3" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="49" Foreground="Red" />
            <Label  Height="35" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="lblStreet1" Content="Street1"  FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="56" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="7" />
            <TextBox  Name="txtStreet1" BorderBrush="#FF179EB7" Text="{Binding Path=Street1,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="129" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="7"  />

            <Label Content="*" Grid.Row="8" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,39,25" Name="lblReqField4" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="49" Foreground="Red" />
            <Label  Height="35" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="lblStreet2" Content="Street2"  FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="56" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="8"/>
            <TextBox  Name="txtStreet2" BorderBrush="#FF179EB7" Text="{Binding Path=Street2, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="8" />

            <Label  Height="35" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="lblCity" Content="City"  FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="16"   VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="49" Grid.Row="9"  />
            <ComboBox Text="{Binding Path=City,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Name="cmbCity" Width="129" Height="25" BorderBrush="#FF179EB7" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="9" HorizontalAlignment="Left"   VerticalAlignment="Top" >
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Kasargod"></ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Kannur"></ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Thrissur"></ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Ernakulam"></ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Palakkad"></ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Alappuzha"></ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Chennai"></ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="WhiteField"></ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Bangalore"></ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>

            <Label  Height="104" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="lblState" Content="State"  FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="16" Margin="0,49,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="142" Grid.Row="9" Grid.RowSpan="4" />
            <ComboBox Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,0,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="129" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="10" Text="{Binding Path=State, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Name="cmbState" BorderBrush="#FF179EB7">
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Kerala"></ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Karnataka"></ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="TamilNadu"></ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="AndhraPradesh"></ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Rajastan"></ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>


            <Label  Height="42" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="lblZipcode" Content="ZipCode"  FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="16"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="142" Grid.Row="11"  />
            <TextBox Name="txtZipcode" BorderBrush="#FF179EB7" Text="{Binding Path=ZipCode,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Height="25"   VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="130" Grid.Row="11" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,0,0,17" />

            <Label  Height="35" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="lblContactInfo" Content="CONTACT INFO" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="20"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="138" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="6" />


            <Label  Height="35" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="lblPhoneNumber" Content="PhoneNumber"  FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="7" />
            <TextBox Height="25" Name="txtPhoneNo"  BorderBrush="#FF179EB7" Text="{Binding Path=PhoneNumber,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="125" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="7" Margin="0,4,0,0" />



            <Label  Height="35" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="lblMobileNumber" Content="MobileNumber"  FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="16"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="109" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="8"  />
            <TextBox Name="txtMobileNo" BorderBrush="#FF179EB7" Text="{Binding Path=MobileNumber,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left"   VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="125" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="8" Margin="29,0,0,0" />

            <Label  Height="35" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="lblEmail" Content="Email"  FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="16"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="56" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="9" />
            <TextBox Name="txtEmail" BorderBrush="#FF179EB7" Text="{Binding Path=Email,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left"   VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="125" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="9" Margin="29,4,0,0" />

            <Label  Height="35" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="lblWeb" Content="Web"  FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="56" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="10" />
            <TextBox Name="txtWeb" BorderBrush="#FF179EB7" Text="{Binding Path=Web,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left"   VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="125" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="10" Margin="29,4,0,0" />

            <Button Content="Update" Command="{Binding UpdateDetailsCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=AllPropertiesValid}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="11" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="40,9,0,0" Name="btnUpdate" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70" Background="Black" Foreground="White">
                <Button.OpacityMask>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
                        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF3870DB" Offset="1" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Button.OpacityMask>
            </Button>
            <Button Content="Cancel" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,9,0,0" Name="btnCancel" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="11" Background="Black" Foreground="White">
                <Button.OpacityMask>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
                        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF29289D" Offset="1" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Button.OpacityMask>
            </Button>
            <Label Content="+91" Grid.Row="7" Height="44" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="132,4,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="33" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
            <Label Content="*" Foreground="Red" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,62,23" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="49" Grid.Row="9" />
            <Label Content="*" Foreground="Red" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,39,23" Name="label3" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="49" Grid.Row="9" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
            <Label Content="*" Foreground="Red" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,39,17" Name="label4" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="49" Grid.Row="11" />
            <Label Content="*" Foreground="Red" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,12,27" Name="label5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="25" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="7" />
            <Label Content="*" Foreground="Red" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,142,27" Name="label6" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="49" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="7" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
        </Grid>
            </Grid>

</Window>
```

Comment: Your question is badly formulated in every way and the code sample is too big..

Comment: Where is your view model?

Answer (score 0):

In your inner Grid you can apply a converter from selected item to visibility.

Add this resource in your XAML:

```
<local:NotNullToVisibilityConverter  x:Key="NotNullToVisibilityConverter" />
```

And use it in your child Grid like this:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Visibility={Binding SelectedEmployee, Converter={StaticResource NotNullToVisibilityConverter}} ...>
```

Here is the converter code:

```
public class NotNullToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return Visibility.Hidden; // or Visibility.Collapsed

            return Visibility.Visible;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```